# What are the $(x,y)$ coordinates for the angles $45^\circ$ and $\pi/2$?

Tags: trigonometry

> What are the (x,y) coordinates for following angles?
>
> i. $\;45^\circ$
>
> ii. $\;\pi/2$

I am trying to solve it by $\tan(\theta)=y/x$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, $\tan \theta = (y/x)$, or $\theta = \tan^{-1} (y/x)$.

Comment: Note that there are an infinite number of $(x,y)$ pairs at those angles from the origin.  Do you want the one that is on the unit circle?  $57$ units away?  Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trigonometry an angle in a triangle can be constructed as part of a right triangle whose lengths are $a_x$ and $a_y$ in those directions. Like for example 100mm in each direction.

An angle by itself has no co-ordinates. A point, either standing alone or when on a line can have coordinates.

$\tan \theta = y/x=1$. Draw a triangle with $45^\circ$ to reference line at any point. with equal side lengths excluding hypotenuse.

$\tan \theta = y/x=\infty$. Draw a line making $90^\circ$ to reference line and with any length of a perpendicular line.

The construction can be shifted/rotated anywhere in x-y plane. So meaning with coordinates here only at the start point.

If you draw a line at $45^{\circ}$ to x-axis passing through $(0,1)$ then you can see a lot of points, including the following points on it.

$$ (-2,-1),(-1,0), (2,3), (9,10) $$

They all have a single equation. In this way you can fix the lines in the plane along with associated inclination angle. The equation of the line they sit upon is:

$ y= x+1$

and a single slope at a constant angle $45^{\circ}$ to x-axis.